# automatically remove elements from the DOM

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a piece of code which adds a div to the document every tenth of a second, animates it a random direction toward the edge of the page and then removes it. At the moment the frame rate is quite low so I was wondering if there's a way to have the div automatically removed when it goes off the edge of the page (left or top value is over 100% or under 0%)

or if there are any other ways to up the frame rate...

here's the code:

```
    function myFunction() {  

//the following generates four random numbers between 100-400 and asigns 2 of them to be the top and left values

var RN=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
var RN2=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
var RNMB4=Math.random()*300+100;
var RNMB2=Math.random()*300+100;
var RNMB3=Math.abs(Math.random()*300) * -1;
var RNMB1=Math.abs(Math.random()*300) * -1;
var NMBRS=[RNMB1,RNMB2];
var NMBRS2=[RNMB3,RNMB4];
    $("<div/>").appendTo('body').animate({
            left: NMBRS[RN] + '%',
            top: NMBRS[RN] + '%',
            }, 
            1000), function(){$(this).remove();});
    }

    setInterval(myFunction,100);
```

Comment: Use firebug or chrome to profile the code. Don't guess where the inefficiency is.

Answer (score 1):

Many times hiding and element is cheaper then removing it from the dom.  I would try calling .hide() on the element when its done being animated.

Depending on how many elements you're going to animate, they may need to be cleaned up eventually.

Also the number of randomly generated numbers can be cut by 2/3. They may be quite expensive to generate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use requestAnimationFrame method to boost animation performance, though this api usually needs vendor-prefix and is not backward compatible.

One more thing is that you should usually, if not always, set the animation element to position: absolute. So that the element will not make the document reflow.

You can use [Greensock](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/), a high-performance js animation library. It also has a jquery plugin to  smooth the animate method in jQuery.

BTW, a needless parenthesis makes your code unmatch... maybe it is a typo when you paste your code?